# Static std::mutex in templated function doesn't work

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

I have a program like this.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>

using namespace std;

template<int Thread>
void run()
{
    for(int j=0;j<5;++j)
    {
        static std::mutex m;
        m.lock();
        cout<<"Thread "<<Thread<<" running... "<<j<<endl;
        m.unlock();

        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(10));
    }
}

int main(int argc , char * argv [])
{
    std::thread t1(run<1>);
    std::thread t2(run<2>);

    t1.join();
    t2.join();

    return 0;
}
```

There is a staic mutex in `run()`to make sure `cout` will be executed exclusively. Howerver, when I run this program with visual studio 2012, the output is:

```
Thread Thread 2 running... 01
 running... 0
Thread 1 running... 1
Thread 2 running... 1
Thread 1 running... 2
Thread 2 running... 2
Thread 2 running... 3
Thread 1 running... 3
Thread 1 running... 4
Thread 2 running... 4
```

It looks the mutex does not work as expected for the first loop in `run()`. Did I make anything wrong with the program?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should place the line:

```
static std::mutex m;
```

outside the body of `run()`. For example, declare it global, on the same level as `run()`.

Since you are using a template, two different `run()` functions are constructed, each one with its own mutex `m`, invisible to each other.

Answer (score 3):

The problem you are facing comes from the fact that your function is a template and such `run<1>` and `run<2>` are not the same and such do not share the same static object.

The solution would be to pass your thread number as an argument to your function.

Answer (score 1):

You have a different mutex in each instantiation of your template. You'll need to make the mutex a global variable or otherwise arrange to use the same one in each function generated from the template.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a problem with std::mutex. Your run function declares two static mutexes, and locks one for each thread.

Consider declaring the mutex in `main` and passing it as a parameter to the function, declaring it globally and locking it in the run function, or making the run function a non-template function.